# Arrange PHP Multidimensional Array By Inner Index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to arrange this array by last inner index ( 0, 1, 2 ) and get the value of the last inner index as the value of each second index:

```
Array
(
    [text] => Array
        (
            [grid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 5
                )

            [image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                )

            [align] => Array
                (
                    [0] => left
                    [1] => right
                    [2] => left
                )

            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                )

            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                )

        )

)
```

And have the results as below:

```
Array
(
    [text] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [grid] => 3
                    [image] => 
                    [align] => left
                    [title] => 
                    [content] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [grid] => 4
                    [image] => 
                    [align] => right
                    [title] => 
                    [content] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [grid] => 5
                    [image] => 
                    [align] => left
                    [title] => 
                    [content] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: are you looking for a one liner solution? Pretty sure the above is trivial using `foreach`

Comment: Where is index [0] in your solution? You only scanned 1 and 2.
These kind of problems can easily be solved by creating a new result-array and using foreach($someArr as $key => $value)

Comment: @SiGanteng I'm looking for a better way to arrange every first array by its child index. The example above use 0, 1 and 2 index. The last child index is start from 0 to any number.

Comment: @Erwin Moller. It starts from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the work

```
function restructure($arr){
    $newArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){
            foreach($v1 as $k2 => $v2){
                $newArr[$k][$k2][$k1] = $v2; 
            }
        }
    }
    return $newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As SiGanteng suggested, i dont see other ways than a `for/foreach` loop:

```
function buildArray($source, $key = false)
{
    // Build the new array
    $new_array = array();
    // Define groups
    $groups = $key === false ? array_keys($source) : array($key);

    foreach($groups AS $group)
    {
        // Get the keys
        $keys = array_keys($array[$group]);
        // Count the values
        $num_entries = count($array[$group][$keys[0]]);

        for($i = 0; $i < $num_entries; $i++)
        {
            foreach($keys AS $key)
            {
                $new_array[$group][$i][$key] = $array[$group][$key][$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

This allow you to define the key you need to build; If not specified, the function build the array for every key.

Comment: your output is different than what the OP asks, please read the output sample carefully

Comment: @SiGanteng youre right, i didnt notice the first `text` index, my bad

Comment: The "text" is the first stage index. How if there is another frist stage array indexes such as "button", "video", etc?

Comment: @zourbuth this depends on how you receive the array and what output you need.
Is `text` a _static_ key (you will always look for, and only for, the `text` index?) In my example I use the first key in the array as _grouping clause_

Comment: @Strae Yes, you are right. The "text" is a unique ID for first dimensional array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
function formatit($arr) {

  $new = array();

  foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    foreach($v as $k1=>$v1) {
     $new[$k1][$k] = $v1;
    }
  }
  return $new;
}
```

Tested. Call it as

```
$arr['text'] = formatit($arr['text']);
```

http://ideone.com/rPzuR

Comment: then maybe you should test it first..?

Comment: @Truth - Call it with the array you want to flip as formatit($arr['text']); http://ideone.com/rPzuR

Comment: @FatalError: Then you should mention it in your answer, don't you think/

Comment: its working bro... but what if the 1st index changes and i want to use the same function at various places with same array structure, but different indexes